# How can I change the directory in Python FTP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, hosting

I have the following code:

```
import ftplib
import easygui

# log in
session = ftplib.FTP(host, username, password)

# upload thumbnail
print('Select your thumnbail')
thumbnail = easygui.fileopenbox('', 'Select your thumbnail')
thumbnailsplit = thumbnail.split('\\')
thumbnailname = thumbnailsplit[-1]
ftplib.FTP.cwd(dirname='/thumbnails')
file = open(thumbnail, 'rb')
session.storbinary(f'STOR {thumbnailname}', file)

# close session
file.close()
session.quit()
```

According to the docs this should change the directory to 'thumbnails' in my FTP server but I get this error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MovieUpload.py", line 13, in <module>
    ftplib.FTP.cwd(dirname='/thumbnails')
TypeError: cwd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The docs state to use it like this:

```
FTP.cwd(pathname)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the instance of ftplib.FTP that you created on login for your ftp operations.

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP(host, username, password)
session.cwd('/thumbnails')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use full path, like this `/home/user/folder/subfolder`